# Expose Docker Ports and Access with DNS for easier Ansible-Access

Tags: docker, dns, ansible, docker-compose

I want to do some testing with Ansible before override the settings on my Liveserver. So I decided to run Ansible against a local docker instance.

Is it possible to expose the ports of the Docker-Contianer to access them over a DNS name like "mailserver.local" / "webserver.local" instead of binding the Ports to localhost?

Finally I'd like to write a docker-compose for my server setup where each docker container ideally behaves like my servers would do without thinking about where the 30st port is binding to on localhost.

> My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Sven Dowideit <SvenDowideit@docker.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server python
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile


EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 110
EXPOSE 143
EXPOSE 25
EXPOSE 465
EXPOSE 587
EXPOSE 993
EXPOSE 995


CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier with Vagrant and the landrush plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll tell you how I do it (although I'm thinking about my 30th port bind to localhost):

- I run my container with `-p 10022:22 -p 10080:80 -p 10443:443`
- I have `127.0.0.1       <containername>` in my `/etc/hosts` file
- I    have `<containername>:10022` in my ansible inventory file

That way you can easily run any playbook you want to test against a single hostname.

You might also automate the revert of your container - e.g. if you want to do a clean run of a play, you need a stock image of the container. A bash script will do the job for that - something which does `docker stop containername`, `docker rm containername` and then `docker run ...`.

Comment: the problem I want to avoid is that if I'll do it this way I can't access the services over their native ports you always have to access your pages over <containername>:10080. I thought about an nginx reverse proxy, but am not that familiar with this approach

Answer (score 1):

i'm using traefik now, solved all my problems